# What association I should to use?

Tags: cakephp-2.4

I have table something like this (for example, it's Comment model):

```
id | user_id | text | created | modified
```

How can I associate this model with User model in CakePHP 2.4?

*P.S. Sorry for my english.*

Answer (score 1):

From your (very) brief description, the relation seems to be "User hasMany Comment" and "Comment belongsTo User".

Usually when in your table you have a column called 'something_id', it means that the model corresponding to this table has a 'belongsTo' relationship with the 'Something' Model. The inverse relationship is hasMany or hasOne depending of the number of instances that 'Something' can be associated with.

For more information you should read [some documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

Comment: I want Comment has Owner. Comment.user_id link with User.id